# Examples of -webkit-appearance settings

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, webkit

Does anyone know of a website or blog that demonstrates - with functioning examples - all the various `-webkit-appearance` CSS settings? The trial and error approach is getting old.

Bonus points if there's further explanation of various of [these -webkit styles](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles)

Comment: Just threw this together: http://jsbin.com/evifa/5/edit
Not really what you are looking for but you might figure some stuff out messing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this - http://css3please.com/.

It allows you to try out samples on the fly, gives you the code you need along with all the vender specific prefixes...

Answer (score 0):

Found a useful link have a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FCSS%2FCSS_Reference%2FWebkit_Extensions

Very nicely given with browser compatibility.